# How can I get the bottom of a div baseline aligned with the text on either side?

Tags: css, inline, vertical-alignment

I am trying to get some text to be baseline aligned with an adjacent `div`, and not with the text content in that `div`. I would like to do this without creating a new browser layer.

I've tried a number of approaches, including all the various `inline-` options for the `div`'s `display` style, aligning text at the bottom of one of the `div`s, etc. No matter what I do, the text outside the `div` ends up aligned based on the text inside the `div`.

This exemplifies what I want vs. what is actually happening.

```
<div class="cell">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    I want this
    <div class="placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cell">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    Not this
    <div class="placeholder">
      text here messes things up
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.cell {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.innerContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I also have it in a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2fjcgn4x/

And here is a screenshot of what the fiddle generates:
[Picture of what I want vs what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPjUa.png)

I can do this using absolute positioning of the text in the div, but it boggles my mind that you can't tell the browser to use a particular element or set of text as the basis for the alignment.

Comment: vertical-align is your friend here https://jsfiddle.net/hnwzqfoe/ or https://jsfiddle.net/js9qgnaw/

Comment: In both of those examples, you lost the white space for descenders beneath the red box, as shown in the original fiddle.

Comment: have you tried to manage this with a padding on the parent .... or read about vertical-align ? figured out why baseline has a gap ... gpy *(letters)* needs it ;) Its indeed all about inline-level style, inline-boxes or text or both mixed on the same html tree level.

Comment: what do you mean by descenders ? are they here in the question or is it becoming another question ? ;) beside this margin/padding option https://jsfiddle.net/qz6dogxp/

Comment: Descenders is a typography term describing letters that drop below the baseline. The baseline is where most of the letters sit. Letters like y, q, g, etc. all drop below the baseline. Inline text elements leave space for those descenders, which is why you see a gap between the red square and the container div's border below it.

Comment: Here is another picture that may help you understand the goal. I've drawn the baseline, and it makes it very clear that, in my first example, the baseline of the text is exactly at the bottom of the div to its right: https://imgur.com/a/siZXntf

Comment: The margin/padding solution you proposed added 3.2px of height. Also, I want a solution that works for any font.

Comment: You also need to learn a bit more about CSS , inline and text  element sit on the baseline. dig a bit more into what `vertical-align` use are and what it does, then tell us if you still cannot do anything with it. Also, avoid *I want* , it can annoye people willing to help.

Comment: My original question states exactly the problem - the baseline of the text should sit at the same spot as the red div to the right. You can already see in the first case, this is happening. In every solution where there is text in the div on the right, the baseline of the text on the left no longer aligns with the bottom of div on the right. I have found no solution where vertical align solves this problem. My apologies that you were annoyed, but if you understand baselines of text, the question seems very clear to me, so I'm not sure what more clarification I can provide to not annoy you.

Comment: don't be annoyed ;), maybe 2 boxes side by side would fit your requirement via vertical-align, since css is unable to select text itself aside font and color. see http://www.html-5.com/tags/div-tag/index.html#syntax  . html tag can hold flow content or phrasing content, while using the right tags , styling becomes much easier . this might help you too http://www.html-5.com/tags/html-tag-list.html#flow-content-model

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for the `.innerContainer`. Adding `display: flex` and `align-items: end;` is enough to get the expected result. In general, [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) is the preferred method for solving these kinds of problems.

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obfzen8a/)

Comment: That did not align the base of the text on the left with the base of the red box, which is what I am trying to do. It also did not leave the extra space for descenders beneath the red box.